# Peewee - How do i execute raw query and map it to the dictionary?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I've been trying to execute a raw query and map it to the dictionary.

While `execute_sql` doesn't return column name, it returns tuple.

I use raw query but it returns None Abc instances

```
class Abc(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    engine = CharField()

q = Abc.raw('show table status from ' + config.DB['name'])
print(list(q.execute()))
```

Output:

```
[<Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>, <Abc: None>]
```

The result from sql

[image]

Comment: display `'show table status from ' + config.DB['name']` and you it directly in database to see what you get.

Comment: @furas i updated the question with example fields from query

Comment: as for me you can't use `Abc.raw` because it will try to convert result to `Abc` but your result has nothing to do with `Abc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is better method but using `execute_sql` and `cursor.description` with names of columns I can create list with dictionares for all tables

```
import peewee

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase('my_database', user='my_user' password='my_password')

cursor = db.execute_sql('show table status from my_database')

all_tables = []

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    table = dict()

    for column, value in zip(cursor.description, row):
        column_name = column[0]
        print(column_name, '=', value)
        table[column_name] = value

    all_tables.append(table)

print(all_tables)
```

Result for one of my database:

```
[
 {'Name': 'alembic_version', 'Engine': 'InnoDB', 'Version': 10, 'Row_format': 'Dynamic', 'Rows': 0, 'Avg_row_length': 0, 'Data_length': 16384, 'Max_data_length': 0, 'Index_length': 0, 'Data_free': 0, 'Auto_increment': None, 'Create_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 17, 19), 'Update_time': None, 'Check_time': None, 'Collation': 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'Checksum': None, 'Create_options': '', 'Comment': ''}, 
 {'Name': 'users', 'Engine': 'InnoDB', 'Version': 10, 'Row_format': 'Dynamic', 'Rows': 0, 'Avg_row_length': 0, 'Data_length': 16384, 'Max_data_length': 0, 'Index_length': 65536, 'Data_free': 0, 'Auto_increment': 2, 'Create_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 17, 19), 'Update_time': None, 'Check_time': None, 'Collation': 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'Checksum': None, 'Create_options': '', 'Comment': ''}, 
 {'Name': 'woocommerce', 'Engine': 'InnoDB', 'Version': 10, 'Row_format': 'Dynamic', 'Rows': 0, 'Avg_row_length': 0, 'Data_length': 16384, 'Max_data_length': 0, 'Index_length': 16384, 'Data_free': 0, 'Auto_increment': 3, 'Create_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 17, 19), 'Update_time': None, 'Check_time': None, 'Collation': 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'Checksum': None, 'Create_options': '', 'Comment': ''}
]
```

---

**EDIT:** the same but with list comprehension

```
import peewee

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase('my_database', user='my_user' password='my_password')

cursor = db.execute_sql('show table status from my_database')

column_names = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
all_tables = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

print(all_tables)
```

Comment: Thank, i didn't know about the existance of `cursor.description`

Answer (score 0):

In peewee, `Model.raw()` is intended for hand optimized `select` statements on the model, not general select statements - it returns instances of the model with the declared fields filled in from the select results. That is, if you have `Wiget(Model)` with fields `length`, `width`, and `height`, a query like:

`wigets = Wiget.raw('select length from wigets where width > height')`

...will return an iterable `wigets` of instances of `Wiget` with the field `length` of the returned values, and `width` and `height` as `None` because they're not in the selection list. `select * ...` will match all columns returned to `Wiget` fields and fill them in.

If the query result doesn't match the schema model (such as your `show table status ...` example), it'll still return one instance of `Wiget` per row returned, but can't match any returned column to the model you defined, so they're all left as `None`.

An important note, SQL is not case sensitive, but peewee is, so a query with `SELECT LENGTH WHERE ...` (or `select *` if the columns in the initial `create table` statement were upper case) will not populate the `length` field because the different cases mean they won't match. Maybe that'll be fixed in the future.