How can I execute combined multiple queries using peewee execute_sql
USE_DB_POOL = db_pool_enabled() and not is_test_environment()
if USE_DB_POOL:
    db_manager = PooledDatabaseManager(db_config)
else:
    db_manager = DatabaseManager(db_config)

class MySQLClient(DBClient):
  def op(self, qry):
        self.reconnect_if_needed()
        cursor = None
        data = None
        try:
            cursor = self.db.execute_sql(qry)
            data = cursor.fetchall() 
            self.db.commit()  # Commit for all executed queries
            logger.info(f"Query executed successfully: {qry}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error executing query: {e}")
            self.db.rollback()  # Rollback in case of error
        finally:
            if cursor:
                cursor.close()
        return data

Above is my code in python. I am trying to run the same sql query using BigQuery or MySQL , My service was already using peewee library with above mentioned connection pool.
The sql query I want to execute is having multiple update queries separated by semi colon. and a START TRANSACTION in the beginning. But I am getting error saying issue in my sql. The same query worked well with mysql connector library. Please help

Many database libraries don't allow multiple queries in a single call. Why do you think you need to do that? As long as all the calls use the same connection the transaction will persist.

The reason was I didnt want to make much code changes. Just wanted to know if multiple quries are allowed some way.

I also wanted to know.  Currently the result is returning with index not by column name, any stright way to fetch with column name?

As far as I can tell, Peewee doesn't have an option for a dictionary cursor like mysql-connector does. So you'll have to create the dictionary yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219520/peewee-how-do-i-execute-raw-query-and-map-it-to-the-dictionary
